# Can't get my Tomcat to connect using port 443 (https)

Tags: ssl, tomcat, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

for the past two days I've been trying to do one thing, be able to access my webapp (localhost:8080/evop) as www.gestao.com.br and furthermore enable https on my web server so that https://www.gestao.com.br also works.

---

### Summary

**I need to have a localhost web application showing the https in front of it's URL (not the crossed red https).**

**PS: Using Tomcat as the web server and Windows and the host OS.**

---

### Explanation

We install Tomcat on each client so they can run our webapp locally at their companies, after sometime we started receiving some complaints that the connection is not secure, even though they are locally, so in order to please our client we decided to enable SSL on their Tomcat servers locally.

Using the keytool provided with JDK it was quite easy to enable https on the server, however the https was crossed by a read line because it was self-signed. At this point I knew a CA was needed to sign the certificate, but since this was all done locally and there were no real domains bought, using a CA like LetsEncrypt was not possible.

So enough of a background story, basically I have a Tomcat server on a Windows 10 machine and it needs to have a signed SSL certificate so the applications hosted on that server have **https in front of their urls (not the crossed https)**

---

### What I did

In order to do that I found out I was gonna have to be my own CA. Here are my steps:

### 1. Being able to access my webapp using only a local domain `www.gestao.com.br`

- My webapp url was `localhost:8080/evop`; However, I changed `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` by adding `127.0.0.1 www.gestao.com.br` to the end of the file, so I could access it using `www.gestao.com.br:8080/evop`
- I solved the port in the URL problem by editing the `server.xml` on Tomcat conf folder and adding:

```xml
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" />
```

- With that I was able to access it using `www.gestao.com.br/evop`
- Last step was to change the folder called `evop` on Tomcat's webapps folder to ROOT and I was able to load my application with `wwww.gestao.com.br`

### 2. Becoming my own CA

- Created a private key with:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootSSL.key 2048
```

- Created the root certificate file:

```
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootSSL.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootSSL.pem
```

- Added my new created root certificate to Microsoft Management Console (MMC) so Windows knows it can trust certificates signed by me.

### 3. Creating and signing a certificate for my own application

- Created a private key for the new local domain with:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out gestao.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout gestao.key -subj "/C=BR/ST=MS/L=Campo Grande/O=Evop/OU=Dev/CN=www.gestao.com.br/emailAddress=dev@evop.com.br"
```

- Issue the certificate with:

```
openssl x509 -req -in gestao.csr -CA rootSSL.pem -CAkey rootSSL.key -CAcreateserial -out gestao.crt -days 500 -sha256 -extensions "authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer\n basicConstraints=CA:FALSE\n keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment\n  subjectAltName=DNS:www.gestao.com.br"
```

### 4. Configure Tomcat to use the certificate

- I tried this two ways, first I opened a powershell on Tomcat conf folder to use `rootSSL.pem` to create a keystore using JDK's keytool with:

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.jks -trustcacerts -file rootSSL.pem
```

- Then I also added the local domain certificate with:

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.jks -file gestao.crt
```

- After that I configured a connector on `server.xml` like so:

```xml
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="443" />

<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" compression="on" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile="conf/tomcat.jks" keyAlias="tomcat" keystorePass="password" clientAuth="false" SSLVerifyClient="none" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" />
```

- However I was only able to access Tomcat using the 8080 port, if I tried to access it using port 443 I got a connection refused error.
- Secondly I tried not using the keytool and setting the local domain certificate and key directly into the conector, like so:

```xml
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
 maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/gestao.key" certificateFile="conf/gestao.crt" type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

- However, that also did not let me connect using the 443 port.

---

### References

> - [Wil Brown’s article - Be your own certificate authority (CA) and issue certificates for your local development environment and get HTTPS working in Windows 10.](https://zeropointdevelopment.com/how-to-get-https-working-in-windows-10-localhost-dev-environment/)
> - [How to install an SSL certificate on a Tomcat server](https://www.ssls.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-a-tomcat-server/)

Comment: Well, in the part #4 you write you have `<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="443" />`, but then _I was only able to access Tomcat using the 8080 port_ - so at which port does the Tomcat run? Have you inspected the `catalina.out` log file if there are no errors on Tomcat startup?

Comment: The thing could be you have to be root to be able to use ports below 1024 - so the connectors are not started.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I added that `Connector`, the regular connector on port 8080 still there as well. The server starts properly because I am able to access it using the 8080 port.

Comment: But you are not able to access 80/443 port! The connectors start independently, if one fails, the others may still start and work. So check the logs.

Comment: Just checked, there are no errors in the lo. I'm able to access port 443 directly if I generate a keystore with a single key in it but as I described the https has a crossed red line on it. I suspect the error is related with how I'm generating the keystore.

Comment: Clients need to trust your own CA. You can't just declare yourself a CA and then issue certificates that everyone trusts. Do you have a plan to distribute your CA's root (or intermediate) certificates?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I do not plan on distributing certificates, this is just for localhost use. I just need a localhost server to have a regular https on its URL. I added my CA to Microsoft Management Console (MMC) so clients would trust me, is it not the way to go? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try using port 8443 for SSL.